# JavaScript File API, can't access file's content

Tags: javascript, file, input, filesystems

I have the following code to read several text files and return an array of objects containing these files's details and contents :

```
var getFilesContents = function( fileInput ) {

    var fileCount = fileInput.files.length,
        results = [ ];

    // Pushing meta datas
    for( var f = 0; f < fileCount; ++f ) {
        var file = fileInput.files[f];
        results.push({
            name   : file.name,
            mime   : file.type,
            format : file.name.match(/\.[0-9a-z]+$/i)[0].substr(1),
            size   : file.size
        });
    }

    // Pushing contents
    for( var f = 0; f < fileCount; ++f ) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
            results[f].content = this.result;
        };
        reader.readAsText( fileInput.files[f] );
    }

    return results;
};
```

The files details are correct, but for some reason the content is always undefined. Am i accessing the right property (this.result) ? What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What browser, platform? Caniuse is worth a visit

Comment: Waterfox 18 (which is very likely to be up-to-date concerning the File API), Windows 7 x64. I'm getting the same result on opera 12.15

Comment: Ok i got it, i'm returning result before the files are read, and array is a scalar type, a copy is returned without the contents. Am i right ?

Comment: @Virus721 - Correct, the FileReader and FileAPI functions are by default asynchronous.  Your code is written in a Synchronous fashion so yes, you are returning results before you ever set the .content on its items.  

The type of results is irrelevant for the most part, especially if your code immediately after this function is trying to make use of the results returned.  In time if it was a type that is passed by reference then the .content property would be set, but timeouts would be sinfully bad when you should just either program async or use the sync functions.

Comment: @Virus721 Well, it's just that you're not waiting long enough (since the reads are asynchronous). Since you're probably accessing the `return` value of this function right after calling it, the values at that point are undefined. If you used callbacks, or `setTimeout` (for testing), you could wait until the array's objects are up to date

Comment: Well i've added an alert() which i leave open several seconds before accessing the results, but i'm still getting underfined. I'll try with a setTimeout. EDIT, seems to work. thanks for your help.